# Is there a way to define CLIPS rules in order to search text?

Tags: clips

I'm trying to define some rules with CLIPS for searching pieces of text in paragraphs or documents (e.g. filter the words that contain the letter 'a' or search for words that appear more than once), but I cannot find any example. Where can I find some examples for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Within your rule patterns you'd place constraints either on multiple words from your paragraph (such as to see if the same words appears more than once):

```
CLIPS>   
(deftemplate paragraph
   (multislot words))
CLIPS> 
(defrule more-than-once
   (paragraph (words $? ?w $? ?w $?))
   =>
   (assert (more-than-once ?w)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule print-more-than-once
   (more-than-once ?w)
   =>
   (printout t "'" ?w "' appears more than once." crlf))
CLIPS> 
(assert (paragraph (words the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
'the' appears more than once.
CLIPS>
```

Or you'd place them on a single word:

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule contains-e
   (paragraph (words $? ?w&:(str-index "e" ?w) $?))
   =>
   (assert (contains ?w e)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule print-contains
   (contains ?w ?l)
   =>
   (printout t "'" ?l "' is contained in '" ?w "'." crlf))
CLIPS> (run)
'e' is contained in 'the'.
'e' is contained in 'jumped'.
'e' is contained in 'over'.
CLIPS>
```